# Angular: How to load secured images inside innerHTML

Tags: angular, typescript

What's the best way to load secured images (images which are accessible via authorization header) inside an `innerHtml` element.

I know, it's possible to load secured image, using a pipe like:

```
<img [src]="'http://secured/image/url' | authImage | async"/>
# or
<img src="{{ 'http://secured/image/url' | authImage | async}}"/>
```

```js
export class AuthImagePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  async transform(src: string): Promise<string> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': `Bearer token`});
    try {
      const imageBlob = await this.http.get(src, {headers, responseType: 'blob'}).toPromise();
      const reader = new FileReader();
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
        reader.readAsDataURL(imageBlob);
      });
    } catch {
      return 'fallback.png';
    }
  }

}
```

but,don't know how to apply this logic to all images inside an innerHtml content. Please note that, the contents of the innerHtml is dynamic & might change based on the user-input.

Comment: I'd create a `Directive` that sanitize the content of the element specified. https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: If I understood correctly, u mean to change image urls & append `| authImage | async` to them, then bypass angular's security controls to be able to parse these changes. right ?
if so, ...
1. I'm wondering if there's any better way of doing this, because in this case (since the user will provide the contents of the innerHtml), it might introduce security risks (user might add extra script which end up in being picked in this scenario)
2. how to apply this pipe to all images inside innerHtml ? regex ?

Comment: Umh, no I didn't meant that. Dom Sanitizer allows you to render whatever you want into an element (such as divs, for example) and it's secure. The directive is needed in order to write just on phrase instead of writing a poem on every element you want to render something (an image in your case)

Comment: Now I understand Jacopo. Thanks. I created the directive & it's working for innerHtml content. I was using `selector: 'img',` as selector to apply to any image tag & then I'm checking the src to see if the headers are required for that src url & it's working! There's only one issue left: the approach works fine for innerHtml, but it does not work for the wyswyg editor that I use. I mean, seems that the directive won't pickup the img tags inside the wyswyg editor. Is it because of the fact that wsywyg editor dynamically creates tags, or it's because it's a third party library used in angular ?

Comment: Sincerely I've never heard this library before, so at this moment I have no idea why isn't working for you. I'll look up to this - if the lib is free to use.

Comment: Thanks Jacopo. I think I should give up on this. I'm using Ckeditor5  (which is a free wyswyg editor), so now the goal is to to show authorized image within the editor. I solved the problem of showing authorized images in innerHtml (while viewing the doc), & I wanted to do the same in editor(while adding/editing the doc)-which I failed (because directive didn't pick up images within the editor). but anyway, even if I succeed in this, it means that the editor will contain (& send) base64 version of the image (not the url of the uploaded image) to the server which is not what I initially wanted.